# Angular - Material Stepper Skips one step on Next Step Click

Tags: angular, angular-material-stepper

In Angular-12 I am implementing Material Stepper:

```js
@ViewChild('stepper') stepper!: MatHorizontalStepper;
isLinear = true; 
districtInfoForm!: FormGroup;
zonalInfoForm!: FormGroup;
groupInfoForm!: FormGroup;
regionInfoForm!: FormGroup;
stateInfoForm!: FormGroup;
countryInfoForm!: FormGroup;

ngOnInit() {
  this.createEmployee();
}

districtNext() {
  if (!this.districtInfoForm.valid) {
    this.districtInfoForm.markAllAsTouched();
    return;
  }
  this.stepper.next();
}

zonalNext() {
  if (!this.zonalInfoForm.valid) {
    this.zonalInfoForm.markAllAsTouched();
    return;
  }
  this.stepper.next();
}

groupNext() {
  if (!this.groupInfoForm.valid) {
    this.groupInfoForm.markAllAsTouched();
    return;
  }
  this.stepper.next();
}

regionNext() {
  if (!this.regionInfoForm.valid) {
    this.regionInfoForm.markAllAsTouched();
    return;
  }
  this.stepper.next();
}

stateNext() {
  if (!this.stateInfoForm.valid) {
    this.stateInfoForm.markAllAsTouched();
    return;
  }
  this.stepper.next();
}

countryNext() {
  if (!this.countryInfoForm.valid) {
    this.countryInfoForm.markAllAsTouched();
    return;
  }
  this.stepper.next();
}
```

HTML

```html
<div class="card-body">
  <mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="isLinear" #stepper labelPosition="bottom">
    <mat-step [stepControl]="districtInfoForm">
      <ng-template matStepLabel>District</ng-template>
      <form>

        <div class="card-footer">
          <button mat-raised-button color="primary" matStepperNext (click)="districtNext()">Next</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step [stepControl]="zonalInfoForm">
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Zonal Info</ng-template>
      <form>

        <div class="card-footer">
          <button mat-raised-button color="black" matStepperPrevious>Back</button>&nbsp;
          <button mat-raised-button color="primary" matStepperNext (click)="zonalNext()">Next</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step [stepControl]="groupInfoForm">
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Group Info</ng-template>
      <form>

        <div class="card-footer">
          <button mat-raised-button color="black" matStepperPrevious>Back</button>&nbsp;
          <button mat-raised-button color="primary" matStepperNext (click)="groupNext()">Next</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step [stepControl]="regionInfoForm">
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Region Details</ng-template>
      <form>

        <div class="card-footer">
          <button mat-raised-button color="black" matStepperPrevious>Back</button>&nbsp;
          <button mat-raised-button color="primary" matStepperNext (click)="regionNext()">Next</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step [stepControl]="stateInfoForm">
      <ng-template matStepLabel>State Details</ng-template>
      <form>

        <div class="card-footer">
          <button mat-raised-button color="black" matStepperPrevious>Back</button>&nbsp;
          <button mat-raised-button color="primary" matStepperNext (click)="stateNext()">Next</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step [stepControl]="countryInfoForm">
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Country History</ng-template>
      <form>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
          <button mat-raised-button color="black" matStepperPrevious>Back</button>&nbsp;
          <button mat-raised-button color="primary" matStepperNext (click)="countryNext()">Next</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step>
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Review</ng-template>
      <h5 style="color:blue;">You are now done.</h5>
      <hr>

    </mat-step>

  </mat-horizontal-stepper>
</div>
```

When the form controls are there it skips only the first step. That is, from District to Group. Then I removed the form controls, it skips one step on each click Distict -> Group -> State -> Review

But the back button is not like that.

What could have caused this and how do I resolve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's becouse `matStepperNext` attribute on your button for next. This attribute is emmiting .next() function on stepper by itself, and your doing it second time inside your (click) functions.

Remove this.stepper.next() from functions:

- districtNext()
- zonalNext()
- groupNext()
- regionNext()
- stateNext()
- countryNext()

also i would suggest to change all those methods to one:

```
nextValidation(form: FormGroup) {
  if (!form.valid) {
    form.markAllAsTouched();
    return;
  }
}
```

and pass specific FormGroup in html;

Comment: @JacekRatejewski - I did this on each matStepperNext.Next() but got this error:    Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': 'matStepperNext.Next()' is not a valid attribute name.     Or how do you mean?

Comment: I mean attribute matStepperNext alone is enough. You dont need additional this.stepper.next() in each method.

Comment: Remove this.stepper.next() from all methods.

Comment: I edited my answer, maybe its more understandable now ^^